# how to update real time field value in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, java-8

I wish to keep a real time variable on a page which can be modified by anyone. But if anyone modifies its value on UI, it would be changed on everyone's UI. its there any way it can be achieved using threads in spring? Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: you can simply to use an application scope variable is ok.

Comment: I could use it, but I want it to be time bound so as to calculate whether other people have the time to update value or not. Plus how can I update the raltime values? Subscribe and public method?  Thanks!

Comment: how about  [tag:websocket]?

Comment: @holi-java I looked into it as well. But since I have only one variable(the timer), will it be worthy to use?

Comment: @holi-java is probably right, you could use ajax probably too, but you *do* need some sort of long-pooling or web sockets, the latter would be favored, but its not supported by all browsers IIRC and it's not *that* easy to get right on the back-end side, again *IIRC*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, we can use one the spring mechanism for RT updates.

1. WebSocket
2. HTTP Streaming
3. HTTP Long Polling

Please refer [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/08/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-techniques-for-real-time-updates/) for detail information.